# Reading data from the widget in wxpython

Tags: wxpython

[image: Simple GUI]

I am wondering how to read the data of start Address and End Address from the TextCtrl box once I click the OK button in the picture attached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to call each of the text control's `GetValue()` methods. 'GetValue()` returns whatever is in the text control.

So let's say that the start address text control is called `self.start_address`. In you button's handler, you would do something like this:

```
def on_ok(self, event):
    start_address = self.start_address.GetValue()
```